# constraint Layout EditText next to Text

Tags: android, constants, android-constraintlayout

I'm designing `layout` for **quiz app** , I'm using `constraint layout` but I want `editText` next to Text not down

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text|textPersonName"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question1Header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question1"
            android:layout_width="248dp"

            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="is a new wave of technology where computing takes place everywhere and anywhere. "
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answer1" />
```

[image: like this in qustion 2]

like here in question 2

Answer (score 0):

Check this. add `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf`

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/question1Header"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:text="1. Complete"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text|textPersonName"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/question1Header" 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: i try but there was no change